# How to express "to go to the other side of the room in the direction that we want"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request, idioms

Ok, this is a picture of my apartment.

[image]

There are 2 adjacent rooms. There is a balcony. The child is standing in Room 1. The child can go from Room1 to Room2 through route 1 (the child can walk down room 1 and go to room2) or route 2 (the child can walk from room1 to the balcony and then go to room2)

I am working on the balcony and it is very dirty. I want the child to go from room1 to room2 and I don't want him to use route 2, I want him to use the route 1.

**How would I say?**

**-Please go to the other side of the room via *something*?**

Comment: Did you try pointing?

Comment: "Go round by the [other] door."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again you are way overthinking this kind of basic communication. Children are no pre-programmed robots who only respond to commands phrased in one way.  You need to communicate, not learn thousands of incantations.

Try

> Go that way.

With body language.

Comment: Is this a complete sentence "go that way to the other side of the room"?

Comment: "Go that way" is a complete sentence.